# Sql Server 2008 express recursive query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

i have three tables t1,t2, and t3.  t1 has my first point

```
--------------------------
| t1
--------------------------
| objectId, x, y     <--(these are fields)
--------------------------
| 30536, 1364690.09169,16518759.7879
|
--------------------------
```

t2 has my several polylines which these are the endpoints to them

```
--------------------------
| t2
--------------------------
| objectId, from_x, from_y, to_x, to_y     <--(these are fields)
--------------------------
| 43664, 1364815.8770, 16518764.8200, 1364806.6780, 16518760.9000
| 43665, 1364806.6780, 16518760.9000, 1364710.2130, 16518719.7700
| 43666, 1364710.2130, 16518719.7700, 1364709.4300, 16518720.3000
| 43667, 1364709.4300, 16518720.3000, 1364690.0920, 16518759.7900
| 43370, 1364843.6870, 16518667.7600, 1364815.8770, 16518764.8200
|-------------------------
```

t3 has my final end point of my entire line

```
--------------------------
| t3
--------------------------
| objectId, x, y     <--(these are fields)
--------------------------
| 11191, 1364843.68657, 16518667.7589
|
--------------------------
```

I did round down to two decimal places so end points match at one point or another.
what i need to do is create some type of recursive query to complete the line from start to all connecting polylines to the final end point.  Now some polylines do not always start from -> to it could be the other way around to -> from so kind of like a combination.  In this example

The line (30536 -> 43667 -> 43666 -> 43665 -> 43664 -> 43370 -> 11191) and reach my final destination.  So all i need is the start point (30536) and end point (11191) in my result.

Comment: i did multiple (up to three) self joins on t2

Comment: Unfortunately there are some polylines that are from -> from

Comment: ex. endPoint <- to_from (polyline) -o- (polyline) from_to -> endPoint

Comment: I updated my answer, now the from-> from is fine too. I changed the SQLFiddle too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not an easy one, but I could make an example.

Here is an [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a61c1/1) with a basic table structure like yours and with the `CTE` solution.
Basicly achive recursive query you need `CTE`. But it is a bit harder since you have 3 different tables. Instead of this it will be much easier if you could define all points in one table and for the start and end points you can add a not existing value. (Even NULL).

**Table structure:**

```
CREATE TABLE startpoint(
  id int,
  x int,
  y int
)

CREATE TABLE points(
  id int,
  fx int,
  fy int,
  tx int,
  ty int
)


CREATE TABLE endpoint(
  id int,
  x int,
  y int
)

INSERT INTO startpoint VALUES(1, 1,1)
INSERT INTO startpoint VALUES(6, 2,4)
INSERT INTO points VALUES (2, 1,1 , 2,1)
INSERT INTO points VALUES (3, 2,1 , 2,2)
INSERT INTO points VALUES (4, 2,4 , 2,5)
INSERT INTO points VALUES (7, 2,5 , 3,2)
INSERT INTO points VALUES (8, 3,2 , 3,3)
INSERT INTO points VALUES (9, 3,3 , 3,4)
INSERT INTO endpoint VALUES(5, 2,2)
INSERT INTO endpoint VALUES(10, 3,4)
```

**Query:**

```
WITH CTE_Points
AS
(
   SELECT
  -1 AS FromID,
  s.ID AS ToID,
  -1 AS fx,
  -1 AS fy,
  s.x as tx,
  s.y as ty
  FROM startpoint s
  WHERE s.ID = 6

  UNION ALL

  SELECT 
  cte1.ToID AS FromID,
  points.ID AS ToID,
  points.fx,
  points.fy,
  points.tx,
  points.ty
  FROM points
  INNER JOIN  CTE_Points cte1 ON (points.fx = cte1.tx AND points.fy = cte1.ty)
  OR (points.tx = cte1.fx AND points.ty = cte1.fy)
  WHERE points.ID != cte1.ToID AND points.ID != cte1.FromID 

  UNION ALL

  SELECT
  e.ID AS FromID,
  -1 AS ToID,
  -1 AS fx,
  -1 AS fy,
  -1 AS tx,
  -1 AS ty
  FROM CTE_Points
  INNER JOIN endpoint e ON (CTE_Points.fx = e.x AND CTE_Points.fy = e.y)
  OR (CTE_Points.tx = e.x AND CTE_Points.ty = e.y)
  OR (points.fx = cte1.fx AND points.fy = cte1.fy)
  OR (points.tx = cte1.tx AND points.ty = cte1.ty)
  WHERE e.ID != CTE_Points.ToID AND e.ID != CTE_Points.FromID 

  )
SELECT FromID AS ID FROM CTE_Points
WHERE FromID != -1
UNION
SELECT ToID AS ID FROM CTE_Points
WHERE  ToID != -1
```

You can try it changing the s.ID from 6 to 1, how is it selecting the two "way" separatly.

(**NOTE:** This only works if you have no connections in your table like: 
Record1.FromX = Record2.FromX AND Record1.FromY = Record2.FromY)